# solr increment numeric fields that are indexed but not stored

Tags: solr

Is there a way to increment a numeric field in solr that is indexed but not stored?

I.e. I have

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="n">10</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

And the schema is something like:

```
<field name="n" indexed="true" stored="false" type="tint" />
```

And I want to do an update on n where for example i increment the current value by some value m.

The only thing I can think of is to make the value both stored and indexed, and then when I want to update the value I have to query solr to get the existing value then call the update endpoint to write out the new value. Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLR-139](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-139) was recently committed that will allow adding etc,  but:

- fields must be stored
- Fix Version is not set but I guess is only on trunk